# Test to use to measure the association of half-deciles

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, chi-squared-test

I'm querying a large (100 million row + ) SQL Server database and doing some preliminary work on the correlation between visits to the emergency room and total healthcare costs.  I ran a query and the data is returned to me in something like looks like:

```
personID     num_er_visits_half_decile     total_costs_half_decile
1            1                              3
2            8                              3
4            9                              6
```

Here a half-decile is like a quartile, but at the 5% level.  So from the table we can read that person 1 is in the 5th percentile for the total number of ER visits, and is in the 15th percentile for overall total costs.  Both of these variables are continuous and the sample size is ~70,000.  Would this be a statistically relevant comparison - comparing the percentiles of ER visits to the percentiles of total healthcare costs?  If so, what would be the best test to use in this situation?  I have access to multiple types of software to perform the analysis, but I don't know what might be the most prudent test to use.

Comment: The right way to model your data depends crucially on what you want to know, so I guess it depends. As far as running Pearson's correlation (or Spearman's), you should know that the results are strongly dependent on the range of your X variable, whereas the sampling distribution of the slope for a typical regression model remains centered on the true value. Again, which you should do depends, but it's something to keep in mind. Lastly, note that you have measurement error (ie on 0-5%, not 2.217%), this will result in bias, w/ betas closer to 0 that actually true.

Comment: could you expound on this measurement error?

Comment: You are only being told that that individual falls somewhere w/i a half-dectile, but you don't know exactly where. Thus, their true position might be at 2.217%, but you only know that they exist in the interval (0, .05). You can get an unbiased estimate by guessing 2.5%, but it will rarely be exactly right. This means that you will have measurement error in X. You can read about this [on the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models#Motivational_example).

Comment: @gung This is not measurement error: it's *censoring* (within intervals) or, if you like "error" terminology, it's rounding error.  The probability model for censoring is different from measurement error; in particular, residuals are usually *not* symmetrically distributed or iid.

Comment: @whuber, I agree that interval censoring is a better framework. I should have been more careful about that. Shouldn't the effect be the same, though: attenuation / sampling distributions of betas biased towards 0?

Comment: @gung It depends on what procedure you use! Once you recognize this is censoring, *no* familiar test will be applicable, because all the familiar ones (from the textbooks) require the data to be numbers rather than intervals. In the present instance I haven't any idea yet what kind of "comparison" is intended--regression, contingency table, comparison of distributions?--so I'm not in a position to recommend anything in particular.  However, I see no *a priori* reason to suppose that a procedure appropriate for such data would necessarily be biased.

Comment: @whuber, sorry, I didn't mean the *appropriate* analysis (of which, I'm not sure either). I was warning against the naive (OLS) methods.

Comment: @whuber i honestly wasn't all that sure about the data either :).  this was just a first pass through attempt at seeing if there was any correlation.  and now i have saved some time by knowing that it's not very sound to compare intervals like this.  good to know :)

Comment: @gung OLS seems pointless with $10^8$ records: surely one can do far better than fitting some linear function to these data!  I would start by *describing* and *exploring* the data.  For instance, an *interval scatterplot* would be a simple $20$ by $20$ grid whose cells are symbolized to represent counts; displaying this would reveal everything there is to be found in these bivariate data. Formal tests are likely to be pointless, given the large number of cases.  Wootscoot: it's perfectly sound to compare intervals; there's no inherent problem with such data.

Comment: BTW, a "half-decile" is technically known as a [vigintile](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vigintile).